# How to query with calculated field and conditions in a find method?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I really have no clues how to do this. Basically in my documents I have a rate, and I want to find the documents that have a calculated rate lower than a value. The calculated rate is as follow:

```
if (rate < 20) {
    calculated_rate = rate * 1.25;
} else {
    calculated_rate = rate + 5;
}
```

Comment: Did you try [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html)? It allows aggregation operators within the _find_ query.

Comment: I will try, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$addFields" : { 
                "calculated_rate" : { 
                    "$cond" : [
                        { 
                            "$lt" : [
                                "$AreasServedRateAndConditions.CGHourlyRate", 
                                20.0
                            ]
                        }, 
                        { 
                            "$multiply" : [
                                "$AreasServedRateAndConditions.CGHourlyRate", 
                                1.25
                            ]
                        }, 
                        { 
                            "$add" : [
                                "$AreasServedRateAndConditions.CGHourlyRate", 
                                5.0
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "$and" : [
                    { 
                        "calculated_rate" : { 
                            "$lte" : 25.0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```